# MapReduce - reducer does not combine keys

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a simple map reduce job where I am building reverse index.

My mapper works correctly (I checked that) and outputs the key pair of word and docID:TFIDF value:

Mapper (only the output shown):

```
context.write(new IntWritable(wordIndex), new Text(index + ":" + tfidf));
```

The only job of reducer is to combine these values. This is my implementation:

```
public static class IndexerReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, IntWritable, Text>
    {
        public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (Text value : values)
            {
                sb.append(value.toString() + " ");
            }

            context.write(key, new Text(sb.toString()));
        }
    }
```

However, it does not combine anything and the output looks basically the same as form the mapper. There are lines in the output with same key although the reducer was supposed to combine them - basically all the keys in the output file are supposed to be unique when using reducer, right?

This is a sample of how my reducer output looks like (note that this is simplified example):

```
1 15:2.1
1 13:4.3
2 9:9.3
2 43:7.9
etc
```

I expected this:

```
1 15:2.1 13:4.3
2 9:9.3 43:7.9
```

For sake of completeness, I am including the run method:

```
@Override
    public int run(String[] arguments) throws Exception {
        ArgumentParser parser = new ArgumentParser("TextPreprocessor");

        parser.addArgument("input", true, true, "specify input directory");
        parser.addArgument("output", true, true, "specify output directory");

        parser.parseAndCheck(arguments);

        Path inputPath = new Path(parser.getString("input"));
        Path outputDir = new Path(parser.getString("output"));

        // Create configuration.
        Configuration conf = getConf();

        // add distributed file with vocabulary
        DistributedCache
                .addCacheFile(new URI("/user/myslima3/vocab.txt"), conf);

        // Create job.
        Job job = new Job(conf, "WordCount");
        job.setJarByClass(IndexerMapper.class);

        // Setup MapReduce.
        job.setMapperClass(IndexerMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(IndexerReducer.class);

        // Sort the output words in reversed order.
        job.setSortComparatorClass(WordCountComparator.class);


        job.setNumReduceTasks(1);

        // Specify (key, value).
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        // Input.
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inputPath);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

        // Output.
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputDir);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);

        // Delete output directory (if exists).
        if (hdfs.exists(outputDir))
            hdfs.delete(outputDir, true);

        // Execute the job.
        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    }
```

I would be glad for any hint about what is going on. I am new to map reduce. Thanks for any debugging tips!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always use the `@Override` annotation.

You defined

```
public static class IndexerReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, IntWritable, Text>
```

Then your reduce method must look like that

```
@Override
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
```

Comment: Interesting, havent thought of that. My IDE does not let me do that (it produces exception: The method reduce(IntWritable, Iterable<Text>, Reducer<Text,IntWritable,IntWritable,Text>.Context) of type Indexer.IndexerReducer must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: Exactly, because it's wrong. Note that I swapped the `key` and `values` type for you.

Comment: but the pair that I am passing to reducer is <InWritable, Text> so IntWritable is supposed to be the key.. right?

Comment: Ok, I swapped it on both lines (even the reducer) and now it lets me override - I will try to run it and accept if it works

Comment: No, Input = `Text, IntWritable`, Output = `IntWritable, Text`. Please read the documentation :)

Comment: Is my output from map wrong then? I need to save my data in form wordID (IntWritable) and some statistics (Text) like I am passing it from mapper

Comment: Then you need to define the generic arguments in the Reducer the other way around. The order is: `MapOutputKey, MapOutputValue, ReduceOutputKey, ReduceOutputValue`

Answer (score 0):

@context is NOT org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context type.
Our Reducer has our own Inner Class type of Context.
So do NOT USE "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context", just use "Context"
This will make sure @Override can be added to reduce function without error.